# Joomla Tags fields, resets when editing articles on frontend

Tags: joomla-3.x, tags

I'm having a little annoying issue about the Joomla Tags component

We use this component for our site, but when you edit an article on front-end, the Tags fields under the 'Publishing' tab is blank, like it been reset.

This is quite annoying for our front-end users, cause every time you hit "Edit article" you have to remember to re-assign the Tag it had before saving.
Somehow the Tag assigned to the article gets removed or reset every time you edit a article on front-end.

Anyone know how such issue can be fix this?
So that the Tags get "memorized" and don't reset every time a article is edited from front-end?

On back-end it works fine and I don't have to re-select the Tags every time I edit a article there, but our moderators don't have back-end access and are not supposed to either.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested on my testing installation and tags are not being reset. I was checking it in the Protostar template.

Can you test in on the Protostart template? Do you have any overrides which could affect the edit form and remove the tags? May be some plugin or something.

What I want to say is that in standard Joomla installation everything works fine.

Comment: Okay thanks, I've tested in the protostart template which doesn't have any template overrides and the issue was still the same. So I believe it gotta be a plugin or one of my extensions causing it then